# Backtracking to generate all numbers within constraint

Tags: python, backtracking

I am trying to create a function that generates all numbers that can be formed through a combination of primes that satisfy the constraint of being within 99% of a certain number and to be less than or equal to that number.
the primes are 
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43]
and the exponents are
[39, 19, 9 , 6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

the code that I currently have only uses one of each prime and then stops,
so like 2^1*3^1*5^1*...*17^1 or something, it doesn't increment the exponents. I am not sure what is wrong here, I don't know where the problem is. Here is my code

```
def rec(start):
    global freqA
    global A
    global exp
    if start >=length:return True
    print A," ",freqA
    if A>= int(0.99*curt):
        for i in xrange(length):
            exp[i]=exponents[i]-freqA[i]
        rec1(0)

    for i in xrange(exponents[start]):

        freqA[start]+=1
        A*=primes[start]
        if A<=curt and  rec(start+1): return True
        freqA[start]-=1
        A/=primes[start]
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

line

```
exp[i]=exponents[i]-freqA[i]
```

not in loop

just in case: 17! = 355 687 428 096 000

Comment: What is the 17! Supposed to mean? I changed it and still doesn't work.